# Gradient estimate of Dirichlet Heat kernel (Classical Laplacian)

Tags: laplacian, heat-equation, kernels

Let $p^D(t,x,y)$ be the heat kernel for the Dirichlet Laplacian in an open set $D$.  Do we have the following estimate and where can I find it ? $$\lvert\nabla_xp^D(t,x,y)\rvert\le C\dfrac{1}{\min (\operatorname{dist}(x,D^c),\sqrt{t})}p^D(t,x,y) \quad \forall x,y\in D,\, t\in(0,T).$$

Comment: Not without some smoothness assumptions on the set. Heat kernel estimates like this follow from Schauder theorems, which you can find in any reasonable book on parabolic equations (e.g. Lieberman, Ladyzhenskaya Uraltseva, Davies, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry i can't seem to find it, could you be more specific please?

Comment: You should quote @user378654 so that he receives a notification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user378654.  I still can't find this upper bound for the gradient. Could you please be more specific ?

Comment: For Schauder theory, see something like Theorem 4.27 in Lieberman's book ("Second-Order Parabolic Differential Equations"). Now that I look at your statement here more closely, however, I am not as sure my previous comment was accurate: it is _possible_ that this follows purely from interior estimates (and so is true on arbitrary domains). The reason I thought it did not at first is that the point you use on the right is at the same time $t$ as the point on the left: the Harnack inequality for the heat equation only controls the past by the future.

Comment: Maybe to clarify further: you can show something like $|\nabla p(t, x)| \leq C/d \max |p|$ where $d$ is parabolic distance to the boundary and the max is taken over a cylinder of parabolic size d centered around $(t, x)$, using just interior estimates for the heat equation (e.g. Lieberman Theorem 4.8). To replace the max with just $p(t, x)$, you can argue that $cd \leq p(t, x) \leq C d$, which follows from boundary regularity (and requires a smooth enough boundary). I don't know if this is true with no assumptions on the boundary, though; this seems related to "backward Harnack inequalities."